# GAPI: Failed to request account data

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

```
Exception: GAPI: Failed to request account data. Error: 

 " Error 404 (Not Found)!!1 *          
 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
code { font: 15px/22px arial,sans-serif }
html {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
    padding: 15px;
}
body {
    margin: 7% auto 0;
    max-width: 390px;
    min-height: 180px;
    padding: 30px 0 15px;
}
* > body {
    background: url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;
    padding-right: 205px;
}
p {
    margin: 11px 0 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ins {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a img { border: 0 }
@media screen and (max-width:772px) { 
    body {
        background: none;
        margin-top: 0;
        max-width: none;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}


404. That's an error. The requested URL 
         /analytics/feeds/accounts/default?start-index=1&max-results=20 
was not found on this server. That's all we know. "
```

Comment: Is that a question? That endpoint no longer exists. Find a more recent GA library.

Comment: it is version 1.3 see that link: https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Comment: That library hasn't been updated since 2009. There have been 2 iterations of GA's data export/reporting API since then. I believe Google provides a 1st party GA API client library for PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, GAPI has not been updated for a long time, and yes, Google does provide a first-party PHP library and a tutorial. Which are both a mess, and are way overblown for tiny-scale scripts.

But you can repair GAPI in no time by following this thread: https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/detail?id=84

In particular, you need to patch the head of the GAPI class, replacing with the following.

```
const client_login_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
const account_data_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles'; //https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default
const report_data_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data';
```

From there on it works as expected.

Comment: +1 also including the head patch info in the answer and not just a link.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idition to Palantir's answer.

In addition to patching the head the following lines need to be altered to get rid of an "undefined variable" error:

```
$account_root_parameters['startDate'] = strval($google_results->startDate);
$account_root_parameters['endDate'] = strval($google_results->endDate);
```

should be:

```
$account_root_parameters['startDate'] = strval($xml->startDate);
$account_root_parameters['endDate'] = strval($xml->endDate);
```